# After I upgrade "jest-dom" to "react-router-dom", all my Test suite failed. And the error is related to the "Jest encountered an unexpected token"

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library, babel-jest

I updated my React test package from "jest-dom": "^3.2.2" and "react-testing-library": "^7.0.0" to "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5" and "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0". But all the test suite failed and I got below error.
"Test suite failed to run

```
Jest encountered an unexpected token



This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.



By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".



Here's what you can do:
 • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
 • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
 • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.



You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
```

https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

```
Details:



C:\VScodeProjects\Project\UpdateTest\my-react-app\node_modules\@testing-library\dom\dist\label-helpers.js:32
    return element.labels ?? [];
                           ^



SyntaxError: Unexpected token ?



  at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:537:17)
  at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:579:25)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/queries/label-text.js:9:21)"
```

I did some research, I tried to write a jest.config.js, but it will get other error like "Invalid testPattern". I put my jest.config.js below

```
const config={
"transform": {
      "\\.js$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest"
    },
};
module.exports = config;
```

Comment: Your title doesn't match the body of your message, and neither upgrade path makes sense; those packages use each other, they aren't replacements for each other. What did you _actually_ start with, and what did you _actually_ end with?

Answer (score 0):

The code transformer doesn't transform the [Nullish coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing) correctly. Queries like [`ByLabelText`](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/bylabeltext) will call [`getRealLabels()`](https://github.com/testing-library/dom-testing-library/blob/v9.3.1/src/label-helpers.ts#L41) function which use that operator. That's why you got the error.

If you use jest with babel, please follow [getting-started#using-babel](https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-babel) guide.

We need to use [`@babel/plugin-transform-nullish-coalescing-operator`](https://babeljs.io/docs/babel-plugin-transform-nullish-coalescing-operator) to transform the nullish coalescing operator(`??`) correctly.

> NOTE: This plugin is included in `@babel/preset-env`, in ES2020

So we can use `@babel/preset-env` instead of adding each babel plugin one by one.

Besides, you don't need to set the [`transform`](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#transform-objectstring-pathtotransformer--pathtotransformer-object) option because the default value of it is:

> Default: `{"\\.[jt]sx?$": "babel-jest"}`

A working example:

`package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "with-jest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.22.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.22.5",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.5.0",
    "jest": "^29.5.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.5.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  }
}
```

`jest.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  testEnvironment: "jsdom",
};
```

`babel.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    ["@babel/preset-env", { targets: { node: "current" } }],
    "@babel/preset-react",
  ],
};
```

`__tests__/index.test.jsx`:

```
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import React from "react";

describe("first", () => {
  test("should pass", () => {
    render(
      <label>
        Username <input />
      </label>
    );
    const inputNode = screen.getByLabelText("Username");
    expect(inputNode).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
> with-jest@1.0.0 test /home/lindu/workspace/with-jest
> jest

 PASS  __tests__/index.test.jsx
  first
    ✓ should pass (21 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.793 s, estimated 1 s
Ran all test suites.
```